# stopMonitoringForRegion with dummy lat long but the right "identifier"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am scheduling and canceling region monitoring in my app as follows.

```
- (void) setLocationReminderForLatitude:(double) latitude longitude:(double) longitude radiusInMetres:(double) radius withIdentifier:(NSString *) identifier
{
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) radius:radius identifier:identifier];
    [coreLocation startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:50]; //50 metres
}

- (void) cancelLocationNotification:(NSString *)identifier
{
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 0.0) radius:100.0 identifier:identifer];
    [coreLocation stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
```

While canceling the region monitoring, I might not necessarily have the centre and radius information that I initially used to start monitoring that region, but the identifier is right. Will this work?

The documentation doesn't mention anything about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pull the correct region to disable the monitoring. What I would do is loop through all the regions enabled and just stop monitoring the one that matches your identifier.

```
for (CLRegion *region in [locationController.locationManager monitoredRegions]) {
    if (region.identifier isEqual:yourIdentifier]) { // change this to match your identifier format
        [locationController.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }
}
```